# Shape of predictors for geospatial 3D CNN

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network

I can't get my mind around how to build a 3D CNN in python to account for spatial features. I have one target variable (binary classification) and say three predictor variables (continuous). All variables have 35 timesteps, 137 latitudes and 181 longitudes. I made a dummy script

```
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv3D, MaxPooling3D, Flatten, Dense

### Generate dummy variables
np.random.seed(42)
predictors = np.random.rand(35, 137, 181, 3)
target = np.random.rand(35, 137, 181)

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv3D(32, 
          kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), 
          activation='relu', 
          input_shape=(35, 181, 137, 3)))
model.add(MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(2, 2, 2)))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(1))

model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mean_squared_error')
model.fit(predictors, 
          target, 
          epochs=10, 
          batch_size=32, 
          validation_split=0.2)
```

but when I try to fit my model, I get the error

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer "sequential" is incompatible with the layer: expected shape=(None, 35, 181, 137, 3), found shape=(None, 181, 137, 3)
```

Why this is happening? I know this a noob question, but if someone could help me solve this and explain what is going on that would be great! Eventually the model should be able to predict along the time axis, i.e. based on the 3 predictor variables.

Answer (score 0):

Try this example then:

```
import numpy as np
from tensorflow.keras.models import Sequential
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv3D, MaxPooling3D, Flatten, Dense

# Generate random fake images
np.random.seed(42)

# set the parameters for the dataset
params = {
    'num_samples': 100,
    'timesteps': 10,
    'height': 8,
    'width': 8,
    'channels': 3
}

# fake image generate function
# it should contain 'num_samples' for the number of samples.
def generate_fake(*args, **kwargs):
    fake_images = np.random.rand(**kwargs)
    # Generate random fake target labels (binary classification)
    fake_labels = np.random.randint(0, 2, size=(kwargs['num_samples'],))
    return fake_images, fake_labels

def create_model():
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Conv3D(32, kernel_size=(3, 3, 3), activation='relu', input_shape=(timesteps, height, width, channels)))
    model.add(MaxPooling3D(pool_size=(2, 2, 2)))
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(64, activation='relu'))
    model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
    return model

fake_images, fake_labels = generate_fake(**params)
model = create_model()
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy', metrics=['accuracy'])
model.fit(fake_images, fake_labels, epochs=10, batch_size=32, validation_split=0.2)
```

#### Use this function to group a simple timeseries to timeseries groups

```
def group_timeseries_images(timeseries, window_size):
    num_timesteps = timeseries.shape[0]
    num_groups = num_timesteps - window_size + 1
    timestep_groups = np.empty((num_groups, window_size))
    for i in range(num_groups):
        timestep_groups[i] = timeseries[i:i+window_size]
    return timestep_groups

# use it like this:
samples = group_timeseries_images(images, window_size=3)
```

But the labels you have to construct yourself, I fear ...

Comment: Thank you so much - this is running - but I don't quite understand how this translates to my problem. What is the ```num_samples``` parameter here?

Comment: In the previous code you generated just 1 image. now 100 3D "pictures" are generated. So you need 1 additional dimensions `num_samples` to deal with the different pictures. I chose low numbers because memory easily runs out in a notebook with just 4 GB ram ...

Comment: matching the shapes is always the most tricky part with CNN models ...

Comment: you can pack parts into functions for the reusability of the code's sake.

Comment: Ok I understand the logic of your snippet but it is still not clear to me how I can apply this to my problem. I can't just invent a new fourth dimension for my dataset. Do I need to subsample my full predictor and target dataset to somehow create a new 4D dataset from it?

Comment: how does your data look like? Ah probably you have just a series of images? Hm yes. It all depends on what problem exactly you want to solve. And yes, you will at the beginning to have to group the images (timeseries of images) to sample-groups.

Comment: either non-overlapping groups or overlapping-groups - but that will depend on your exact question/problem you want to answer/solve (or what exactly you want to predict).

Comment: As I said above, I have one target dataset with the shape 35,137,181 for 35 timesteps, 137 latitudes and 181 longitudes. For the predictors it is then 35,137,181,3 where 3 is the number of predictor variables (or channels). So it is basically a series of images as you say, and the goal is to predict an image eventually.

Comment: hm, then probably you want to predict just 3 timesteps with the model? - so you have to subdivide your model into (overlapping?) 3 timesteps groups.

Comment: see second part of my answer.